# Layout in captcha window slightly broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The Captcha's layout seems slightly off:

[image]

Latest stable Chrome on Mac OS X here.

Comment: Those borders keep to be broken. `;)`

Comment: I'm looking into this. I forgot we had a captcha in popup mode too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be on live server after our next prod build(within 24hrs)